# Return only a portion of a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following sample data (4 sample records of one particular field):

```
Adjusted - Above contract rate
Adjusted - Above contract rate / Amount in excess / Coinsurance Amount
Adjusted - Above contract rate / Amount in excess 
Amount in excess
```

I need to return only the part to the left of the first "/" or if there is no "/" return only the first part like:

```
Adjusted - Above contract rate
Adjusted - Above contract rate
Adjusted - Above contract rate
Amount in excess
```

Any clues as the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `SUBSTRING()` with `CHARINDEX()`. For example:

```
select
  case when charindex('/', name) = 0 then name
  else substring(name, 1, charindex('/', name) - 1) end
from t
```

Result:

```
(No column name)
------------------------------
Adjusted - Above contract rate
Adjusted - Above contract rate
Adjusted - Above contract rate
Amount in excess
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AZNgXmC_).

Answer (score 0):

You can create this function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Portion]
(
    @S varchar(max), @C varchar(1) 
)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @P int = CHARINDEX(@C,@S)
    if @P>0
        set @S = substring(@S,1,@P-1)

    RETURN @S
END
```

-- and use it like

```
select [dbo].[Portion]('Adjusted - Above contract rate / Amount in excess','/')
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by The Impaler is fine. The only reason I am posting is because there is another way that I think is easier to understand.

```
Declare @Temp Table(value varchar(100))

Insert Into @Temp Values('Adjusted - Above contract rate')
Insert Into @Temp Values('Adjusted - Above contract rate / Amount in excess / Coinsurance Amount')
Insert Into @Temp Values('Adjusted - Above contract rate / Amount in excess')
Insert Into @Temp Values('Amount in excess')

Select  *,
        Left(Value, CharIndex('/', value + '/') -1)
From    @Temp
```

You cannot have a value less that zero for the second argument of the left function. Therefore, when you charindex, you add a slash to value ensuring that you will never get a zero.

For example, if you consider "Amount In Excess", there is no slash, but when you do:

```
Select CharIndex('/', "Amount In Excess")
```

You would get 0, then you subtract 1 for the second argument, you get:

```
Select Left(ColumnName, 0-1)
```

or

```
Select Left(ColumnName, -1)
```

Which results in a substring error.

However, if you follow the logic of the code I presented, you have...

```
Select Left('Amount in excess', CharIndex('/', 'Amount in excess' + '/') -1)
Select Left('Amount in excess', CharIndex('/', 'Amount in excess/') -1)
Select Left('Amount in excess', 17 -1)
Select Left('Amount in excess', 16)

-- Returns 
Amount in excess
```